# Changing Opacity of Text and Text Bacground separately in Fabric JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, fabricjs

I am adding text to the Canvas using Fabric JS.

```
let text = new fabric.IText('My Text', {
    fill: 'black',
    fontSize: 40,
    textBackgroundColor: 'yellow'
})

canvas.add(text);
```

If I change Opacity of text like this:

```
 text.set({'opacity': 0});
```

It also changes the Opacity of Text Background which I do not want.
I want to change the Opacity of Text without changing it's background.

**Actually, I want to punch out Text or you can say set text opacity to '0' with out changing Backgound of text.**

Like This:

[image]

Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: Text opacity 0 will just mean you can't see the text. Could you explain a bit more what you mean by 'punch out'. It sounds as though you want the text to appear with the background that is behind it's element as its filling. Is that right? ie you 'see' the underlying background through the yellow.

Comment: @AHaworth Yes, I want text to go invisible and see the underlying background of canvas through the yellow background of text. I am updating the question with a reference. You can see that.

Comment: @AHaworth      Please check the picture in question sir, for better understanding.